# cant set cookie(?) i am not sure

Tags: php, html

I had program at localhost and there were cookies and all worked, i mean my "autorisatrion" text changed to "profile" when cookies are set. But when i chanded to the web hosting they suddenly stopped to work. Help me pleeeaseeee
I am really beginner without good background, so please shall you give clear explanation?

Code at autorisation file

```
<?php


                $res=mysqli_query($link,"set names utf8");              
                if (!isset($_COOKIE['id_users'])) { // если сотрудник еще не авторизоавлся, то 
                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  // если нажата кнопка авторизации
                        $user_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim($_POST['email']));
                        $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim($_POST['password']));
                        if (!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) { // если поля не пусты
                            // выполнить запрос: выбрать следующие данные, где эл. адрес и пароль совпадают
                            $query= "SELECT `id_users`, `email`, `privilege` FROM `accaunt_workers` WHERE 
                            email = '$user_username' AND password = '$user_password'";
                            $data = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                            if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) { // если такой сотрудник есть, то создать куки
                                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);

                               setcookie('id_users', $row['id_users'], time() + (60*60*24*30));
                               setcookie('email', $row['email'], time() + (60*60*24*30));

                                // если привилегия сотрудника подходит под определенную опцию, 
                                //то перенаправление на определенную страницу с разными функциями администратора
                                if ($row['privilege'] === 'Все') { 
                                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                                    echo 'window.location.href="admin.php";'; 
                                    echo '</script>'; } 
                                ELSE {echo $row['privilege'],'НЕ Все';}

                                if ($row['privilege'] === 'Работа с клиентами: комментарии и предложенные темы') {
                                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                                    echo 'window.location.href="admin_comment_theme.php";'; 
                                    echo '</script>';
                                } 
                                ELSE {echo " НЕ Работа с клиентами: комментарии и предложенные темы";}
                                if ($row['privilege'] === 'Работа с содержимым: материалы и рекомендации') {
                                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                                    echo 'window.location.href="admin_material_recommendation.php";'; 
                                    echo '</script>';

                                }
                                ELSE {echo 'НЕ Работа с содержимым: материалы и рекомендации';}
                            }
                            else{ echo 'Извините, введены неправильные логин или пароль';} 
                        }
                        else{ echo 'Извините, заполните поля правильно';}

                    } 
                }

            ?>

            <?php
            if(empty($_COOKIE['email'])) { // если пользователь не авторизован, то вывод формы авторизации
            ?>

                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"> 

                    Адрес электронной почты:
                    <input class='enter' type="email" name="email"  required="required" placeholder="abc@mail.ru"   pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z.]{1,}+[a-z.]{1,}$">
                    Пароль:
                    <input class='enter'  type="password" name="password" required="required" pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*">
                    <input class='enter' type='submit' name='submit' value="ВОЙТИ">
                    <footer class="clearfix">
                        <p><span class="info">?</span><a href="forget_pass.php">Забыли пароль?</a></p>
                        <p style="text-align: center; color:grey">*Если вы отсутствуете в системе, напишите на почту kontaev@inbox.ru*</p>

                    </footer>
                </form>

            <?php 
            }
            else { //если пользователь авторизован, то вывод кнопки выхода, так как требуется повторная авторизация для перенаправления
            ?>


                <P><a href="exit_accaunt.php"> Exit </a> </p>

            <?php 
            } 
            ?>
```

and here is code at the headng of file where people go after the autorisation

```
<ul class="menu">    <!-- меню-список страниц-->    

                  <li><a href="index.php">Главная</a></li>

                  <li><a href="about.php">О нас</a></li>

                  <li><a href="materials.php">Материалы</a></li>

                  <li><a href="recomendations.php">Рекомендации</a></li>

                  <li><a href="Contacts.php">Контакты</a></li>

                  <?php

                        //Проверяем авторизован ли пользователь

                        if(!isset($_COOKIE['email']) && !isset($_COOKIE['password'])){

                        // если нет, то выводим ссылку на авторизациию

                  ?>

                  <li><a href="form_auth.php">Authorisation</a></li>

                  <?php

                        }else{

                        //Если пользователь авторизован, то выводим ссылки на выход и профиль

                  ?>

                  <li><a href="admin.php">Profile</a></li>

                  <li><a href="exit_accaunt.php">Exit</a></li>



                  <?php

                        }

                  ?>                 

                </ul>
```

Comment: **Too much code.** You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need to **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck, provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil)**.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `$_COOKIE['password']` but I don't see in the code that you set this cookie.

Change `!isset($_COOKIE['password'])` to `!isset($_COOKIE['users'])`.

Comment: Yep, i changed it to  if(!isset($_COOKIE['email']) && !isset($_COOKIE['id_users'])){          BUuutt it didnt work

Comment: i guess the problem is in the autorisation code. Also I heard somewhere that code with cookie should be at the very beginning of the code, is that true?

Comment: > Also I heard somewhere that code with cookie should be at the very beginning of the code, is that true?
It should be before any output, i.e. before you print any HTML on the page.

Comment: I would start debugging with the DevTools to make sure that cookies are actually set.

Run developer tools --> Application -->Cookies and check if the cookies are set and have correct names.

Comment: I would reverse the logic that check user's authorization:

`if(/*user authorised*/) {
// display content for auth user
} else {
// display login form
}`

Comment: thank you a lot, i think i know that the problem is in the location of code with cookie, it is in the part after html output, but i have now another problem T-T

Comment: i should have connection with database before the cookie part, or is it a mistake?

Comment: Yes, you should have a DB connection before -- you are trying to get the user from before you set the cookies.

Comment: i made it like this, i thought it is suitable for "no html output before cookie" but it is not right, isnt it?

Comment: <code> <?php
    if(empty($_COOKIE['email'])) { // если пользователь не авторизован, то вывод формы авторизации
               
   
           require_once 'db_connect.php';
           $res=mysqli_query($link,"set names utf8");    
           if (!isset($_COOKIE['id_users'])) { // если сотрудник еще не авторизоавлся, то 
           etc/......
           }
             
    
?></code>

Comment: You can set up mysql connection and other unrelated logic before checking for the cookies.

Comment: Did you check that your code actually sets cookies?